# Git post-commit hook written in ruby not running in Git Tower

Tags: git, git-tower

So I've got a basic post-commit hook written in ruby, and I've confirmed it runs when I commit from the command line. It does not, however, run when I commit in Git Tower, and I don't even see any errors from Git Tower appear.

My script begins with:
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and it does run properly when I commit from the command line, so I know its not a problem with the script. Do I need to do something to get my gems to load properly?

Comment: Following https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/221, would a simpler shell script work? `#!/bin/sh
echo "test" >> "post-commit.log" 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation would be that the Git Tower doesn't run in the same shell, with the same environment.

See [its FAQ "Are Hook scripts supported in Tower?"](https://www.git-tower.com/help/guides/faq-and-tips/faq/hook-scripts/mac)

> Please note: Do your hook scripts rely on the existence or on specific values of shell environment variables that are created/modified in your shell profile (like extending "PATH" by a non-standard-path (e.g. '`~/bin`') to run a script from there in the hook)?
>
> If the answer is yes, then you need to make sure you're creating the required shell environment in the hook script itself (like modifying "`PATH`"), not in your shell profile, as the hook script is called from the Tower process environment which is not running in a shell environment (hence your shell profile is not loaded).

In that case, a simple shell script should be your post-commit hook, in order to:

- modify the environment appropriately
- call your ruby script.